# C# SQL Insert row in a defined position

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table with several columns correctly sorted by 3 of these columns. The point now is how to insert a new row in a specific point using these columns. et me do an example, please suppose to have a table like:

```
Name   Order1 Order2 Order3 Address
Marc   30     01     7     Street1
James  30     03     7     Street1
Dan    31     02     5     Street3
Rick   31     02     2     Street1
```

In case I insert a new record (Tony) I can have something like

```
Marc   30     01     7     Street1
James  30     03     7     Street1
Dan    31     02     5     Street3
Rick   31     02     2     Street1
Tony   30     01     5     Street1
```

but the order that I need is

```
Marc   30     01     7     Street1
Tony   30     01     5     Street1
James  30     03     7     Street1
Dan    31     02     5     Street3
Rick   31     02     2     Street1
```

(in details, for order 1 and 2 I need lower number on top, in case of order 3 I need higher number on top).

Do you have any suggestion about how to do it? Simple way is moving along the table and copy the new data ordered in a new one but is quite long...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The only way you're getting physical ordering is with a clustered index or something and even then, the physical ordering of rows is normally largely secondary to the logical ordering of the query you're using to access data.

Comment: There's no order when storing but you can retrieve ordered data

Comment: SQL or relational databases don't have an *inherent* ordering - the data in the tables is by default **unordered** and gets an order **only** if you `SELECT` and explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore, you cannot insert a row in a *specific position* - there is no such thing in a relational database. Just insert the row, and when you `SELECT` from the table, use the appropriate `ORDER BY` to get your ordering!

Answer (score 4):

You generally don't insert data into the middle of a table - inserts are either at the end, or somewhere in the middle if there is a clustered index defined.

Just add the row to the table and then set the order when you *retrieve* the data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM People
ORDER BY Order1, Order2, Order3 DESC
```

If you *need* the physical structure to be in that order then add a clustered index on `Order1, Order2, Order3 DESC`.  But be aware that you *still* need to specify the order when querying because if you do not specify an order in the query SQL can return the records in whatever order it sees fit.

Be aware, though, that inserting into the middle of a clustered index has performance implications since the server *may* need to reorganize the data.  If the table is small it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, this is perfectly clear now.

Answer (score 1):

RDBMSs are generally designed with set theory mathematical concepts at their core.  This enables set based operations (fast) on data as opposed to cursor based operations (slow).  When you think of data stored in a table in an RDBMS, think of it as simply a set of data, which does not imply any order whatsoever.  Indexes can be applied to tables in order to make a subset of the data ordered in order to improve look up speed.  RDBMSs provide operations that you can perform on data in order to make it ordered for retrieval purposes, such as an `Order By` statement.  This will perform a cursor based operation on the data set retrieved in order to sort it according to the parameters defined.  Having this basic understanding of database structure will aid in all aspects of working with an RDBMS, from performing CRUD operations, to optimizing, to proper structure, and so on.

To summarize:

- Data in a table should never be assumed to have any order
- Data inserted to a table should never be assumed to be put in any specific location
- Indexes create an ordered set based on a given column or set of columns, which greatly improve look up speed
- Order is applied to data after a set is retrieved

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, this is perfectly clear now.